# Dynamiclly creating View in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a project with one View. I'm drawing everything on it programically. So when i want to add another View (screen) to my project i create a class inherits from the UIViewController class and implements method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

And then i want to load this View from my original View, and i do this:

In **ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TestViewControllerClass.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource> {
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) TestViewControllerClass *testView;

@end
```

In **ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize testView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    testView = [[TestViewControllerClass alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:testView]; //crash here

}
```

And then in my **TestViewControllerClass.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestViewControllerClass : UIViewController

@end
```

And **TestViewControllerClass.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

To check if method **wiewDidLoad** will be executed i put there a breakpoint, but nothing happend. In fact, my app crash (I put comment at code where).

When crashes i receive: ***-[TestViewControllerClass superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x683aca0***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
[self.view addSubview:testView]; //crash here
```

with

```
[self.view addSubview:testView.view];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code...

```
[self.view addSubview:testView.view];
```

Hope,this will help you...

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is settings your ViewController as the view, not the real view

```
testView = [[TestViewControllerClass alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:testView]; //crash here
```

this will obviously crash. Assuming you have a view variable declared in your header file called view, use

```
testView = [[TestViewControllerClass alloc] init];
     [self.view addSubview:testView.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load two types for uiviewcontroller loading below:

```
[self.view addSubview:testView.view];
```

(or)

use presentmodalviewcontroller below code:

```
    testView *popupView = [[testView alloc] initWithNibName:@"testView" bundle:nil];
    popupView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:popupView animated:YES];
```

dimiss modal view cntroller below code:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

thanks..!